# MySQL varchar to unsigned of alphanumerical

Tags: mysql

I have a `VARCHAR` column that holds user IDs.

Example record IDs, `1001, 1002, 1003`.

I've been using `SELECT MAX( CAST(enduser_id AS unsigned)) as enduser_value` to retrieve the maximum ID. This works for numerical values but when i have an alphanumerical ID, it fails and only returns `0`.

Example alphanumerical IDs, `AC1001, AC1002, AC1003`.

Is there a way i can retrieve the MAX of both ID types using a single query?

Comment: I would urge you to normalise your design

Answer (score 1):

```
select max(CAST((substring(id,3)) AS DECIMAL(5,0))) from table
```

And at the end you can concat AC as well.

```
select concat('AC'+ max(CAST((substring(id,3)) AS DECIMAL(5,0)))) from table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use lpad for fill with 00 the missing char

```
select max( lpad(enduser_id , 6, '0'))  as enduser_value 
from your_table
```

Comment: I see your logic, to my eyes this should work however it isn't preforming the `max()` correctly. Either way, this is the closest answer yet